# Failed to load ressource in Browser Chrome and IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

In my application I am using different fonts and the glyphen-icons of bootstrap.
To see the results in all the browsers, I have put all the neccessary font-types(woff, tft, svg,..) in the font-face. 
For the bootstrap icons, I have just put the neccessary types in the font folder.

If I go localhost, everything works fine. In all the browsers, I can see the results.

But now I deployed my application (war) on a real server. 
In fireFox i can still see the icons and the font, but not in Chrome and IE.
There I get the following error in console:

```
http://myTestServer.com/admin-UI/fonts/source-sans-pro/Source_Sans_Pro_400.woff Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
...
GET http://myTestServer.com/admin-UI/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
GET http://myTestServer.com/admin-UI/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 
GET http://myTestServer.com/admin-UI/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
```

I don´t understand, why does it works local and not on the real server.
Does anybody know this problem?

my Css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url('../fonts/source-sans-pro/Source_Sans_Pro_300.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/source-sans-pro/Source_Sans_Pro_300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/source-sans-pro/Source_Sans_Pro_300.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/source-sans-pro/Source_Sans_Pro_300.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/source-sans-pro/Source_Sans_Pro_300.svg#SourceSansPro') format('svg');
```

Thank you!

UPDATE:

the index.html before (worked only in the localhost sever of spring Boot):

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

index.html after (this works in tomcat and also in myServer)

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS - tomcat-->
<link href="http://localhost:8080/adminUI/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -myTestServer-->
  <link href="http://myTestServer.com/adminUI/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The main.css I also added the absolute path. My question is now, is there a way to replace the absolute path: "http://..../" with a variable.
If I use the relavtive path that would be the same problem like at the beginning.
I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: use absolute path to include font files in css

Comment: whast about the bootstrap font files? Do they also have to be in the CSS? I thought bootstrap automatically finds them in the font folder. And how should I named the fonts of bootstrap, so that it detects the files?

Answer (score 1):

Your fonts and style should be in same parent directory directory like this. Look at fonts and style folder and ignore other folders this is an example.

[image]

then include the bootstrap css in in your document like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/style/bootstrap.min.css">
```

replace example.com with your domain. bootstrap will automatically find the font file in same parent directory. this is absolute path to bootstrap css file.

Comment: Thank you very much. It really worked. But is there a possiblity to get the absoutePath in css? Actually I don´t want to put the absolute path in my css and index.html. In index.html i can use javaScript. But in Css it will be a problem right?

Comment: using absolute path is not a problem. however if you don't want to use absolute path you can use relative path according to root directory. I don't know which hosting you are using. in most cases public_html is our root directory and assume your font and style folder are place in assets folder in public_html then your can use /assets/style/somestyle.css. here / before assets representing the root directory. read mre about absolute and relative path on this page http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: In relative path you can also use ../ to access parent directory ../../ parent of parent. and / to start from the root directory.

Comment: But as you can see I have used this in the css file and index also with css/... But this does not worked. It works only local but not if I deploy it

Comment: can you give the link of page where code is running so I can better guide.

Comment: Unfortunately this not possible. Because were using for the authorization the kerboros. You won´t be able to see anything. But I tried this in the local tomcat. And the same problem occures.  I have put an UPDATE to explain it in detail